# How to use filters in Terraformer for importing AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraformer

I have a lambda named `blog-dev-createArticle` in `us-east-1` region. I am trying to use [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) to generate its `terraform` files.

I am unable to use filters and generate the terraform files for a specific lambda function.
I have tried the following till now but all of them either selects all the lambdas & generates the `.tf` files for them or selects no lambda at all.

```
terraformer import aws --resources=lambda --filter="Name=tags.FunctionName;Value=blog-dev-createArticle" --regions=us-east-1
terraformer import aws --resources=lambda --filter="FunctionName=blog-dev-createArticle" --regions=us-east-1
terraformer import aws --resources=lambda --filter="Type=aws_lambda_function;FunctionName=blog-dev-createArticle" --regions=us-east-1
```

Can someone help me in using filters for `AWS Lambda` with `Terraformer` in the right way?

Comment: If `terraformer` generated the configs for all of the lambdas, then you could always just grab the relevant section for the desired lambda.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yeah..but since terraformer provides filters, we should be able to generate tf files for only the required resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lambda uses `FunctionName` as attribute for name whereas terraform uses `function_name`.
 So, using `function_name` as attribute in filter did the trick.

```
terraformer import aws --resources=lambda --regions=ca-central-1 --filter="Name=function_name;Value=blog-dev-createArticle"
```